# Flutter textfield disable prefix icon on text changed

Tags: flutter

I have a text field widget that has an prefix icon . I want the prefix icon to be hidden when the text field is changed

my code:

```
TextField(
                    controller: messageInputController,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      messageInputChanged();
                    },

                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        counterText: '',
                        prefixIcon: !showPrefixIcon ? Container() :  Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                  imagePickerBottomSheet();
                              },
                              iconSize: 40,
                              color: Skin.gray,
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/svg/ic-image.svg',
                                height: 22,
                                color: Skin.gray,
                              )),
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

```
void messageInputChanged() {
    if(messageInputController.text.isEmpty){
      showPrefixIcon = true;
    }else {
      showPrefixIcon = false;
    }
    
    setState(() {});
    
  }
```

But when the set state is called and the icon is hidden, the contents of the text field are also messed up

Comment: Add full arguments passed in `TextField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InputDecorator accepts a Widget? for the prefixIcon, however, it does not work with a Container(). That's strange.
If I replace your

```
prefixIcon: !showPrefixIcon ? Container() :  Padding(...)
```

with

```
prefixIcon: !showPrefixIcon ? SizedBox(height: 0.0, width: 0.0) :  Padding(...)
```

it works.
I honestly don't know why.

---

updated proposal:
Use:

```
prefixIcon: !showPrefixIcon ? null :  Padding(...)
```

---

And I just assume that you could then reasonably argue that this is ugly. Then, I fear, you have to change the way of doing it to something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 70.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                    transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => SizeTransition(
                        sizeFactor: animation,
                        axis: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: child),
                    child: showPrefixIcon
                        ? const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.abc,
                                color: Colors.blue, size: 46),
                          )
                        : Container()),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageInputController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'enter text',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageInputChanged();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It also works well to switch Icons etc., not just replace one with a SizedBox, but I understood you want to remove the PrefixIcon and I came up with the SizedBox.

Comment: This solution worked. But the text inside the text field has padding on the side because of the prefix icon. How to remove this padding?

Comment: Instead of my idea with the SizedBox, use null like this:
prefixIcon: !showPrefixIcon ? null : Padding(...),

Comment: I've added more in my answer above as I can´t add readable code in the comments. You might argue that with the "null" the transition is super ugly. And therefore I wrote an example of how you could make things nicer.